# Making radio buttons a required selection by user

Tags: php, html

I have 5 radio buttons that offer a range of values :

```
        <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="1"/>1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="2"/>2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="3"/>3<br>    
        <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="4"/>4<br>    
        <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="5"/>5<br>
```

I want it to make sure the user has selected them, because currently the user can not select one and the form will still submit. While I could make one of them "checked", this could mean the user could still submit without actually making a selection.

How can I make sure that when the user hits submit the user has definitely selected one of their of accord.

Comment: is it acceptable to pre-select one for them?

Comment: Use JavaScript to make sure one of them is selected... but it's still possible to disable JavaScript to bypass this check.  Side note: IDs are supposed to be unique in HTML, so you really shouldn't have 5 radio buttons with the same ID (same *name* is required for them to work properly, though).

Comment: javascript:disable submit by default, enable it on any radio-button click.

Comment: As @Powerlord said, You can accomplish this using javascript and, as a side check, you may also check if at least one of the radio have been checked with PHP.

Comment: @briosheje not so sure that you can check more than one radio-button with same name.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: Since they are radio buttons, you should only be checking one of them, not more than one, else you would rather use checkboxes, right? :)

Comment: @briosheje, that's what I said after your "at least one". There's no "at least", just "one" :)

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 The javascript disable would be a really nice touch but the answer below solved it instantly. But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical use-case for [the `required` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-required).

Modern browsers don't let you submit the form if no radio button is selected, even with JavaScript disabled.

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="1" required />1<br />
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="2" required />2<br />
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="3" required />3<br />    
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="4" required />4<br />    
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="5" required />5<br />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/5cJj8/

A simple JS validation for required radio buttons:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener( 'submit', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = event.target,
        radioHasCheckedButton = form.querySelector( 'input[required][name="bookperiod"]:checked' );

    if( !radioHasCheckedButton ) {
        // Error handling here – no radio button was checked
        console.log( 'Some required fields are missing.' );
    }
    else {
        // Everything is fine – finally submit the form
        form.submit();
    }

}, false );
```

Comment: Note this will only work in browsers supporting [HTML5 Form Validation](http://caniuse.com/form-validation).

Comment: @AndersG: That's why I was wondering "what..I've never seen that before"? lol

Comment: nice but not cross-browser

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 Yeah, but standards-compliant. Please use JS to validate the form by yourself for non-supporting browsers – as any web-developer had done the last ten years…

Comment: totally agree with you, just noticed the fact.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like all these answers are barely getting by. First of all: you CANNOT have multiple elements with the same ID. Change that to a class or label each one uniquely!

You cannot skip the PHP check. This must always be done. Please read contents related to server-side vs client-side especially on validation. I won't go into it here.

Adding the client-side (Javascript) check is for user convenience ONLY. This allows the user to know the form is incomplete before hitting the submit button and having to wait on the server.

This can be done in a couple of ways and more...

1. Add an additional radio button with visibility or display turned off with CSS. This would be checked by default. With javascript you can see if this is still the radio button that is selected (meaning the user has not selected one of the visible ones) => display error
2. Iterate over each radio button and ensure one of them is marked checked (standard `if` inside a for loop) untested jqyery code.

   ```
   function validateBookPeriod() {
       var bookperiodSelected = false;
       $('.bookperiod').each(function(){
           if($this.attr('checked') == checked) bookperiodSelected=true;                 
       });

       if (bookperiodSelected == false)
           alert('Please select a book period!');
   }
   validateBookPeriod();
   ```

Comment: In `$this.attr('checked') == checked` there is no definition for `$this` nor for `checked`. Instead of using jQuery just to test the `checked` attribute is not necessary, as that status can directly be read from `this.checked === true`.

Answer (score -3):

you can pre-select one for the user, then the user will be forced to select another option or accept the first

```
    <input type="radio" checked name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="1"/>1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="2"/>2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="3"/>3<br>    
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="4"/>4<br>    
    <input type="radio" name="bookperiod" id="bookperiod" value="5"/>5<br>
```

Comment: learn to read entire questions before posting an answer: **While I could make one of them "checked", this could mean the user could still submit without actually making a selection.** ;)

Comment: Not only that, but using `checked` feels like a hack to me.